# Get Previous 12 months name/id from current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can any one help me in getting the last 12 months names from the current date (month).
I want this query in slq server.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code that you havebeen working on.

Comment: do you want to include current month or only the previous 12 months ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requires sql-server 2008

```
select datename(m,dateadd(m,-a,current_timestamp)) monthname,
       datepart(m,dateadd(m,-a,current_timestamp)) id
from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(a)
```

Result:

```
monthname  id
December   12
November   11
October    10
September   9
August      8
July        7
June        6
May         5
April       4
March       3
February    2
January     1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use common table expression for your solution:

```
;WITH DateRange AS(
    SELECT GETDATE() Months
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(mm, -1, Months)
    FROM   DateRange

    WHERE Months > DATEADD(mm, -11, GETDATE())
)

SELECT DateName(m, Months) AS Months, Month(Months) AS ID FROM DateRange
```

shows previous months in the order:

```
    Months                         ID
------------------------------ -----------
January                        1
December                       12
November                       11
October                        10
September                      9
August                         8
July                           7
June                           6
May                            5
April                          4
March                          3
February                       2
```

Answer (score 1):

why not a simple get date?

```
SELECT name FROM [yourtable] WHERE
[tabledate] >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
```

this what you mean?

On a side note, if this is the solution you need, there are alot of examples around google with a quick search. As this is common statement.